# How can I use a plugin shortcode inside of a html form?

Tags: shortcode, forms

I'm using the Simple Wordpress membership plugin for page access. There is a shortcode that can be used to display the username once logged in.

I have a form that submits a mysql query and creates records. I would like the "Username" field in the form to automatically display the users username. Any ideas?

Comment: This is pretty vague - can you share your code and what the plugin's shortcode is doing?  Rather than use the shortcode though, just retrieve the user's username; if you're writing mysql queries you should be fine just retrieving the username.

Comment: Here is the shortcode, [swpm_show_member_info column="user_name"]. It just displays the username when they are logged in. 

Here is the code for my form, <label>Username</label><input type="text" name="username">

I need the username to be placed in the input so they don't have to fill it in themselves.